Как отследить дату, когда пользователь впервые начал диалог с ботом или залогинился в нём?
Как сделать так, чтобы можно было видеть дату, когда пользователь ввёл впервые \start или залогинился в боте, чтобы ему была видна дата регистрации в личном кабинете?
Код:
from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command

import app.keyboards as kb
import app.database.requests as rq

router = Router()


@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await rq.set_user(message.from_user.id)
    await message.answer(f'Добро пожаловать! Это бот для заработка денег на написании вами отзывов на различных платформах (таких как: Авито, Яндекс, Гугл карты и т. п.)\n Авито отзывы - от 100 до 135 рублей (цена выше чем у других!)\nНачинай зарабатывать вместе с нами\nДля начала работы нажмите на "Каталог отзывов"', reply_markup=kb.main)
    await message.reply('По рекламе или если вы хотите стать заказчиком пишите: @review_manadger')

@router.message(F.text == 'Личный Кабинет')
async def profile(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f'➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\n‍Ваш ID: {message.from_user.id}\nИмя: {message.from_user.first_name}\nЗарегистрирован: {message.from_user.}\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖', reply_markup=kb.profile)


Текущие время -> сохранить в БД. В чем собственно вопрос?

у меня не получалось в бд добавить, просто давало ошибку при запуске

Каждое сообшение в бот от аккаунта приходит в виде:
{
  "update_id": 123456789,
  "message": {
    "message_id": 1234,
    "from": {
      "id": 0000000,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "xxx",
      "username": "xxx",
      "language_code": "ru",
      "is_premium": true
    },
    "chat": {
      "id": 1111111,
      "first_name": "xxx",
      "username": "xxx",
      "type": "private"
    },
    "date": 1724228341,
    "text": "pypypy"
  }
}

и вот message.from.id + совместить message.text, где будет /start и сохранить это все в свою базу с даташатмпом, готово
